# React Native: Get current height and width of Image in 'ImageBackground' after resize mode ''contain" is applied

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

I am selecting an image from gallery and loading it into `ImageBackground(which have fixed height and width)` in react native and `resizeMode` "Contain" is applied on that,

I would like to able to know the current height and width of the image when `resizeMode` is applied .
Thanks